# Access Forms! not working on Updates

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access

I am building an Access database with an Entry form and an Update form.  The main table has several fields that are built from data on the Data Entry form via VBA - short examples:

```
Private Sub Network_Selection_Exit(Cancel As Integer)

PBlue_Network = Forms!frmDataEntry!PBlue_Network

-------------------------------

Form_sbfNetwork Selection

Private Sub Existing_Click()
' Only pull documentation for Requested Networks
If Not Existing = "Existing" Then
If Network_CD = 1 Then Forms!frmDataEntry!PBlue_Network = "AI"
End If
```

The Data Entry form works correctly but the Update form gives me a 2465  using pretty much the same code:

```
Form_sbfNetWork_Update

Private Sub Existing_Click()
' Only pull documentation for Requested Networks
If Not Existing = "Existing" Then
If Network_CD = 1 Then Forms!frmProvUpdate!PBlue_Network = "AI"
End If

----------------------------------------------

Form_frmProvUpdate

Private Sub Network_Updates_Exit(Cancel As Integer)

PBlue_Network = Forms!frmProvUpdate!PBlue_Network
```

I'm not sure where I've gone wrong, but the Update consistently gives the 2465 error

Comment: Carefully check if any control is actually named *PBlue_Network* on update form. Check in Design View / Property Sheet. Recall a control source may not be same as control name.